# Calculating addCurveToPoint control points

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am using CoreGraphics to draw a rounded rectangle, I am familiar with the CG API ready made to draw the rounded rectangle, but I do not want to use it because the rectangle is not a fully-uniform rounded rectangle, part of it would be a rounded rectangle, the other parts would be a set of connected paths, for example, the top-left and top-right would be a rounded rectangle edges, however, the bottom edges are a group of connected Bezier paths.

My question is, if I want to draw the entire shape as Bezier path, how should I calculate the control points in addCurveToPoint for the corners? I know the radius and the coordinates of the points (based on radius too).

(UPDATE)

```
I have a sample code, I am trying to understand the math behind it:

UIBezierPath * rectangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[rectangle moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 8)];
[rectangle addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(8.01, 0) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(0, 3.58) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(3.59, 0)];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(208, 0)];
[rectangle addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(224, 16.01) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(216.84, 0) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(224, 7.16)];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(224, 175)];
[rectangle addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(192, 207) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(224, 192.67) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(209.67, 207)];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(64, 207)];
[rectangle addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 142.99) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(28.65, 207) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(0, 178.35)];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 8)];
[rectangle closePath];
```

The corners radius are 8, 16, 32 and 64 for top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to add a 90 degree arc for the rounded corner. Use `addArc` instead of `addCurveToPoint`.

In Swift 3:

```
var path = UIBezierPath()

...

let center = CGPoint(x: topLeft.x + width - radius, y: topLeft.y)
path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(1.5), clockwise: true)
```

Of course, your parameters will vary.

**Update**

Based on your code, it should look like this:

```
UIBezierPath * rectangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[rectangle moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 8)];
[rectangle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(8, 8) radius:8 startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI*1.5 clockwise:YES];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(208, 0)];
[rectangle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(208, 16) radius:16 startAngle:M_PI*1.5 endAngle:0 clockwise:YES];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(224, 175)];
[rectangle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(208, 175) radius:32 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*0.5 clockwise:YES];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(64, 207)];
[rectangle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(64, 175) radius:64 startAngle:M_PI*0.5 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:YES];
[rectangle closePath];
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have a sample code to what I want, but I can't figure out the math behind it:

Comment: @Nader See my update above... `center` is the center of arc, i.e. it is offset from the rectangle corner by the radius. If you're interested how an arc is approximated as a bezier curve, see [Approximating a Circular Arc With a Cubic Bezier Path](http://hansmuller-flex.blogspot.ch/2011/04/approximating-circular-arc-with-cubic.html).

Comment: Thanks! This really worked, but I had to modify it slightly :)

Answer (score -1):

Based on @Codo answer, this is the final solution:

```
UIBezierPath * rectangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[rectangle moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 8)];
[rectangle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(8, 8) radius:8 startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI*1.5 clockwise:YES];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(208, 0)];
[rectangle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(208, 16) radius:16 startAngle:M_PI*1.5 endAngle:0 clockwise:YES];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(224, 175)];
[rectangle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(192, 175) radius:32 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*0.5 clockwise:YES];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(64, 207)];
[rectangle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(64, 143) radius:64 startAngle:M_PI*0.5 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:YES];
[rectangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 8)];
[rectangle closePath];
```

Comment: I haven't spotted the difference between your and my code yet. Can you help me?